# Run a build after creating it with DSL Job Plugin

Tags: jenkins

I have successfully programatically created a job with [DSL Job Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin)

I trigger the "job creator" job from gitlab, hitting a post with:

https://37.35.xxx.xxx/jenkins/project/job-creator

So, it create the job, but it is not triggering it... Any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I found out you can use `upstream` trigger:

```
pipelineJob("myJob") {
  parameters {
    stringParam('param1', 'value1') // this will define params for the project build
}

triggers {
    gitlabPush {
        buildOnMergeRequestEvents()
        buildOnPushEvents()
        commentTrigger('Jenkins please retry a build')
        upstream("${JOB_NAME}", 'SUCCESS') // Trigger job after this job ends

    }
}
```